# SqlException: Invalid object name in .core 2.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.1

here is my step to create and link the DB from my program:

1. create a table
2. create the model: Class and DBContext
3. create the Controller by click the button and it would automatically generate both of controller and Viewer
4. check the connection string in appsettings.json
5. add Context ConnectionString in Startup.cs
   and it always got `SqlException: Invalid object name` error
   i am sure my connectionstring is correct because another table connection succeeds in the same DB.

here is my code:

1. `dbo.ProjectLog.sql`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProjectLog] (
    [ID]              INT           NOT NULL,
    [Date]            DATE          NOT NULL,
    [ExeUser]         TEXT          NOT NULL,
    [RD]              TEXT          NOT NULL,
    [Time]            TIME (7)      NULL,
    [Start]           SMALLDATETIME NULL,
    [End]             SMALLDATETIME NULL,
    [Host]            TEXT          NULL,
    [Environment]     TEXT          NULL,
    [ProjectFullName] VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [ProjectName]     VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [ProjectVersion]  VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [Critical]        INT           NULL,
    [High]            INT           NULL,
    [Low]             INT           NULL,
    [MainProjectID]   INT           NULL,
    [Comment]         TEXT          NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

2. in folder`Models`: `ProjectLog.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WebTryLogin.Models
{
    public class Project
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string ExeUser { get; set; }
        public string RD { get; set; }
        public int Time { get; set; }
        public string Start { get; set; }
        public string End { get; set; }
        public string Host { get; set; }
        public string Environment { get; set; }
        public string ProjectFullName { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public string ProjectVersion { get; set; }
        public int Critical { get; set; }
        public int High { get; set; }
        public int Low { get; set; }
        public int MainProjectID { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
    public class ProjectLogContext : DbContext
    {
        public ProjectLogContext(DbContextOptions<ProjectLogContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Project> ProjectLogs { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.ID).HasColumnType("int(8)");
                entity.Property(e => e.Date).HasColumnType("varchar(10)");
                entity.Property(e => e.ExeUser).HasColumnType("varchar(20)");
                entity.Property(e => e.RD).HasColumnType("varchar(20)");
                entity.Property(e => e.Time).HasColumnType("varchar(10)");
                entity.Property(e => e.Time).HasColumnType("varchar(10)");
                entity.Property(e => e.Start).HasColumnType("varchar(10)");
                entity.Property(e => e.End).HasColumnType("varchar(10)");
                entity.Property(e => e.Host).HasColumnType("varchar(15)");
                entity.Property(e => e.Environment).HasColumnType("varchar(50)");
                entity.Property(e => e.ProjectFullName).HasColumnType("varchar(50)");
                entity.Property(e => e.ProjectName).HasColumnType("varchar(50)");
                entity.Property(e => e.ProjectVersion).HasColumnType("varchar(50)");
                entity.Property(e => e.Critical).HasColumnType("int(10)");
                entity.Property(e => e.High).HasColumnType("int(10)");
                entity.Property(e => e.Low).HasColumnType("int(10)");
                entity.Property(e => e.MainProjectID).HasColumnType("int(8)");
                entity.Property(e => e.Comment).HasColumnType("varchar(10)");
            });
        }
    }

}
```

3. create automatic, not special
4. use the `DefaultConnection` that is a initialize value by program
5. in `ConfigureServices` function, add:

```
services.AddDbContext<ProjectLogContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

and i also update DB by command `Update-Database -Context ProjectLogContext` in NuGet Console.

what could i do else?

[UPDATE]

ALL ERROR MSG when i want to view index (list all info by ID in DB `ProjectLog`):

**`An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.`**

```
SqlException: Invalid object name 'ProjectLogs'.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__122_0(Task<SqlDataReader> result)
```

```
DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

**`SqlException: Invalid object name 'ProjectLogs'.`**

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__122_0(Task<SqlDataReader> result)
System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask<TAntecedentResult, TResult>.InnerInvoke()
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, object state)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref Task currentTaskSlot)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> parameterValues, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

**`DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.`**

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(DbContext _, ValueTuple<IEnumerable<ModificationCommandBatch>, IRelationalConnection> parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync<TState, TResult>(TState state, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult<TResult>>> verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IReadOnlyList<InternalEntityEntry> entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
WebTryLogin.Controllers.ProjectsController.Create(Project project) in ProjectsController.cs
+     63.           await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: 1. provide full exception with stacktrace 2. why some fields has different type in model vs `modelBuilder` vs `CREATE TABLE ` (fx: `Start`  : `string`  vs `varchar(10)` vs `SMALLDATETIME`) ?

Comment: Not related to your question, but `TEXT` is deprecated and it has no business being in a table alongside the new `TIME` type. (This is true even if other tables use it for existing data, as it's easily converted.) Use `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, or, better yet, use reasonable sizes for your strings (like `VARCHAR(255)` for `Hostname`). Despite the name, `TEXT` is not a generic string type and should not be used as if it was.

Comment: Your context is `ProjectLogs` (plural), but your table is `[ProjectLog]`. Not being terribly experienced with EF I don't know if it is smart enough to handle pluralization by default or if you need to handle the mismatch another way.

Comment: thanks for all of your advice! this is the first time to use C# connect with SQL, and i have no idea for the type in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Crowcoder is correct in the comments above, but incorrectly associated the convention with the context name. It's actually based on the name of your entity, i.e. `ProjectLog`. By convention, EF will associate that with a table named `ProjectLogs`, plural, and your table is named `ProjectLog`, singular. Long and short: you need to rename your table to `ProjectLogs`.

Also, FWIW, you should not manually create your entity classes or context if you're going to use an existing database, or simply want to go a "database-first" route. Instead, you should scaffold your context and entities into your project, and continue to do so to update them if and when you make changes to the database.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "[connection string]" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models
```

For additional information about using an existing database with EF Core, see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding).

Comment: Tks for your share! After i chg the table name it works! I reference from some articles like this Docs. Maybe i could try another keywords (lol). I even could not sure which DB type i use...(and i see lots of people discuss with EF) now i know it names EF! (I think it is SQL server before)

Comment: EF/EF Core are ORMs (object-relational mappers). They take data from the database and translate into CLR objects, and vice versa. SQL Server is a database, like Postgresql, MySQL, etc. EF works with SQL Server. It's not the same thing.